# Complex includes/excludes with rsync

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to work out the rsync filter syntax to perform complex include/excludes, and trying to achieve the following:

```
Include /
Exclude /home
Include /home/user1/*
Include /home/user2/subdir/*
```

I've tried many variations on the filter syntax, and despite reading the man page many time, I cannot get this sort of effect.  Rsync filters seem to be very powerful, and I find it hard to believe they couldn't handle a common scenario such as this.

Answer (score 20):

You need to include all of the parent directories down to the desired directory before using the exclude rule.

For instance, I use the following in a backup script:

```
rsync -av \ 
--filter='+ /var/' \
--filter='+ /var/backups/' \
--filter='- /var/*' \
/ \
$DEST
```

So in your case you would need something like the following:

```
rsync -av \ 
--filter='+ /home/' \
--filter='+ /home/user1/' \
--filter='+ /home/user2/' \
--filter='+ /home/user2/subdir/' \
--filter='- /home/user2/*' \
--filter='- /home/*' \
/ \
$DEST
```

Comment: Excellent. Took me some time.

Comment: Somehow, when I read the `man rsync`, I misunderstood the proper order of mixing includes and excludes. It took me an hour to figure it out...

Answer (score 6):

On the command line:

```
rsync --dry-run --verbose --recursive --include=/home/user1 --exclude=/home/* / DEST
```

Remove `--dry-run` to make it functional, replace "DEST" with your destination and add user and host to the source "/" if needed.

From a rule file:

```
rsync --dry-run --verbose --recursive --filter='merge /etc/rsync/somerules.rules' / DEST
```

where the contents of `/etc/rsync/somerules.rules` might be:

```
+/ /home/user1
-/ /home/*
```

You should test these and you may need to make some adjustments, but this should get you started.

Comment: OK, that works.  I have a more complex case which I've added to the question.  The additional include doesn't work with the subdir scenario.