# rsync --files-from or --include-from

Tags: rsync

I tried the command:

```
 rsync -v --include-from=/path/to/list.lst /home/user /path/to/backup
```

`list.lst` contains for example

```
.gnupg/

.pki/

.gnome2/keyrings/

.mozilla/firefox/*.default/bookmarkbackups/

.mozilla/firefox/*.default/bookmarks.html

.mozilla/firefox/*.default/*.db

.mozilla/firefox/*.default/*.sqlite
```

and I get error on all strings with:

> failed: No such file or directory

When I use `--files-from` for this, I get an error too. Can anybody help me use wildcards for this?

Comment: Sad... 12 years & not a single useful or correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can go with include filters and `--include-from`: [Complex includes/excludes with rsync](https://serverfault.com/questions/150269/complex-includes-excludes-with-rsync)

Or you can go with a find command:

```
cd
rsync -v --files-from <(find gnupg/ .pki/ .gnome2/keyrings/ \
  .mozilla/firefox/*.default/bookmarkbackups/ \
  .mozilla/firefox/*.default/bookmarks.html .mozilla/firefox/*.default/*.db \
  .mozilla/firefox/*.default/*.sqlite) \
 ~ /path/to/backup
```

Comment: Must i use "find + cat" when i have list.lst with paths to files and directories? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I gave you an example. There is no cat, instead the list.lst was rewritten so that the shell matches your globs. If you rewrite list.lst into rsync filter rules, rsync will do the matching.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to add the `--recursive` option and use `--files-from`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the file name in your `list.lst` must start with `+` or `-` like:

```
- *.o
- foo/
+ *.exe
+ 123/456/*
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is described in the following web page. It looks like that error line is misleading, check the "code" error that comes latter.

http://kenfallon.com/rsync-mkstemp-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-2/

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/60592

I have similar problem with "(code 23)" but I am still don't know why or how to fix it. If I put the files to transfer (foo*.xml) in the command line rather than in the `--files-from` file, it works. I am starting to think that `--files-from` does not like patterns with asterisks, question marks, etc. Perhaps I need to use `--include-from`, the problem is that I found `--include-from` confusing to include and exclude files.

`0     Success
 1     Syntax or usage error
 2     Protocol incompatibility
 3     Errors selecting input/output files, dirs
 4     Requested action not supported: an attempt was made to manipulate 64-bit
       files on a platform that cannot support them; or an option was specified
       that is supported by the client and not by the server.
 5     Error starting client-server protocol
 6     Daemon unable to append to log-file
10     Error in socket I/O
11     Error in file I/O
12     Error in rsync protocol data stream
13     Errors with program diagnostics
14     Error in IPC code
20     Received SIGUSR1 or SIGINT
21     Some error returned by waitpid()
22     Error allocating core memory buffers
23     Partial transfer due to error
24     Partial transfer due to vanished source files
25     The --max-delete limit stopped deletions
30     Timeout in data send/receive
35     Timeout waiting for daemon connection`

Comment: We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the lines in the `/path/to/list.lst` do not have blank spaces at the end of the line. I don't know why `rsync` is so sensitive to that.

Answer (score 0):

It light of @seamus' comment: [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176557/rsync-with-files-from-in-wildcards) explains the use of files-from and include-from.