# Rsync Specific Direcotries and files with the same structure

Tags: linux, rsync

I want to rsync specific directories and files with the same structure

for example :-

```
source/
source/110/var/lib/mysql
source/110/var/lib/mysql
source/110/var/lib/mysql
source/110/home
source/110/bin/
source/110/etc/
source/120/var/lib/mysql
source/120/var/lib/mysql
source/120/var/lib/mysql
source/120/home
source/120/bin/
source/120/etc/
```

how to rysnc mysql and home directories and the files included in the direcotry to the same destination folder and with the same structure to be like the following example :-

```
destination/
destination/110/var/lib/mysql
destination/110/home
destination/120/var/lib/mysql
destination/120/home
```

thanks

Comment: See also this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/150269/complex-includes-excludes-with-rsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with some fancy filters. The man page has a nice example of this, but with a recent rsync (>= 2.6.7) you can do something like:

```
rsync -a source/ destination/ \
    -f '+ /*/' \
    -f '+ /*/home/***' \
    -f '+ /*/var/' \
    -f '+ /*/var/lib/' \
    -f '+ /*/var/lib/mysql/***' \
    -f '- *'
```

In other words, you list which directories you want to **include** in your
sync, and then **exclude** everything else. The `***` wildcard is very useful
but if your rsync is older, you will have to replace the `+ /*/home/***` filter
with the following two:

```
    -f '+ /*/home/' \
    -f '+ /*/home/**' \
```

Comment: is there a way to do it in one comand line so i can set it in cronjob in the server ?

Comment: i tried the command but the command transfer the directory without the files within the directories

Comment: Sorry, I missed a leading slash in the filters. I already corrected my answer and even tried it out. Without the leading slash '+ */' was matching **all directories** and that is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to using filters:

```
cd source && \
rsync -aR  110/var/lib/mysql  110/home  120/var/lib/mysql  120/home  destination
```

That is, you pass all the source directories as arguments to `rsync`, followed by the destination directory, all in one command. You must be certain to use the `-R` option in this case, so that your source directory paths are preserved in the destination.