# Excluding absolute paths in rsync

Tags: rsync

The man page for rsync suggests that I should be able to write

```
-/ /home/me/foo
```

in exclude.foo and then run

```
rsync -a --exclude-from exclude.foo /any/path/ /dest/
```

and have /home/me/foo excluded, but I cannot seem to get it to work (the path is copied).

Does that syntax exclude absolute paths?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex includes/excludes with rsync](http://serverfault.com/questions/150269/complex-includes-excludes-with-rsync)

Answer (score 1):

The exclude should look like this

`- foo`

& the rsync CMD should look like this

`rsync -a --exclude-from=exclude.filter /home /dest`

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Please fix the formatting